# How to kill a spark shell via Spark's REST API?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

I'm running Spark version `2.0.1` and want to kill a spark shell via the REST API (cannot use any other methods such as the yarn commands, for instance).
I managed to get the application id (with the `spark-master:8080/json/` endpoint), but I could not find any API that allows to kill an application based on its ID (I'm familiar with the `http://spark-master:6066/v1/submissions/kill/` endpoint, but the spark shell does not have a driver ID).

So is there a way to kill an application based on its ID, or should i just keep chasing pavements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging (including installing tcpdump on the Spark master server, for listening to REST requests coming from the Spark UI application), I've managed to find the correct request:

```bash
curl -X POST http://{spark-master-server}:{spark-server-port}/app/kill/ -d 'id=spark-shell-app-id&terminate=true'
```